# How can I find all possible sequences of any length within a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops

I want to take a user input (string) and convert it into a list of word combinations (array) of all possible lengths, but only keep the combinations which are in sequence.

So the array listed in the PHP below would eventually read:

`$newArray = ["this","string","will","be","chopped","up","this string","will be","be chopped","chopped up","this string will","string will be","be chopped up"];`

My code (not working) is as follows:

**PHP**

```
$str = "This string will be chopped up.";
$str = strtolower($str);
$strSafe = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-z\s-_]/i","",$str);
$array = explode(" ", $strSafe);
$newArray = [];
$newArrayEntry = [];

for($counter=0; $counter < COUNT($oneword); $counter++) {

    // List single words - as in array $oneword.
    echo "One word: ";
    echo $oneword[$counter];
    echo "<br />";

    $counterTwo = $counter+1;       

    if($counterTwo <= COUNT($oneword)) {
        $newArrayEntry[COUNT($newArrayEntry)] = $oneword[$counter];
        print "Adding counter One to newArray Entry: ".$oneword[$counter]."<br />";
        for($counterThree=($counter+1); $counterThree < $counterTwo; $counterThree++) {
            $newArrayEntry[COUNT($newArrayEntry)] = $oneword[$counterThree];

            if($counterThree - $counterTwo == 1) {
                $newArrayEntry[COUNT($newArrayEntry)] = $oneword[$counterTwo];
                print "Adding counter Two to newArrayEntry: ".$oneword[$counterTwo]."<br />";
            }
        }
        $newArrayString = join(' ', $newArrayEntry);
        $newArray[COUNT($newArray)] = $newArrayString;
    }
}
```

Comment: "string will" is missing...

Comment: You can use push to add values to your array ... and in the counter loop you need another counter as well as far as I can see it to loop through your basic array from different points and different lengths.

Comment: Thanks Medda!

Not sure what you mean trincot.

Comment: What I meant was that you have in the desired output `....."this string","will be"....`, but logically, `"string will", ` should appear between those two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this code:

```
$str = "This string will be chopped up.";
$str = strtolower($str);
$strSafe = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-z\s-_]/i","",$str);
$array = explode(" ", $strSafe);
$newArray = [];

for ($len = 1; $len <= count($array); $len++) {
    for($start = 0; $start+$len <= count($array); $start++) {
        $newArray[] = implode(" ", array_slice($array, $start, $len));
    }
}   


var_export($newArray);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'this',
  1 => 'string',
  2 => 'will',
  3 => 'be',
  4 => 'chopped',
  5 => 'up',
  6 => 'this string',
  7 => 'string will',
  8 => 'will be',
  9 => 'be chopped',
  10 => 'chopped up',
  11 => 'this string will',
  12 => 'string will be',
  13 => 'will be chopped',
  14 => 'be chopped up',
  15 => 'this string will be',
  16 => 'string will be chopped',
  17 => 'will be chopped up',
  18 => 'this string will be chopped',
  19 => 'string will be chopped up',
  20 => 'this string will be chopped up',
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the optimisation, but I need it to also read...

array(...(cont.) 'string will', 'string will be', [...] 'will be', 'will be chopped', 'will be chopped up', 'be chopped', 'be chopped up', 'chopped up')

I think I've solved it. Just going to test this evening and I'll update my question to include the answer. Thanks!

Comment: The values you mention are all in the output, or I don't understand what you mean. As far as I can see the output produced by my code is in line with your question.... Also, please don't put an answer in the question, but instead post an answer ... as an answer.

Comment: Sorry... I completely misread this. I think I had mixed it up with another question.... thanks!!! :)

(I was going to read the rules on answering your own questions before posting... not very well versed in best practices here. Though now I don't need to!)